# dynamic variables between javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a website which does a number of tasks. One task that I need help with involves grabbing distinct variables from a mysql table (that much I can do) and parsing them to a pichart coded in javascript.
As of now, I can grab the database elements using cookies and read them to the pichart but I am having issues building new pichart items should the distinct locations not be pre-programmed. Here is an example of what I have so far.

```
  $inloc = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], "SELECT * FROM _redacted WHERE location LIKE 'certain Area'"));
  $Totalmbrs = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], "SELECT * FROM _redacted"));
  $gone = $Totalmbrs - $inloc ;
  setcookie("TS", json_encode($Totalmbrs));
```

this grabs the data from my table, does some math to find the difference of members who are signed out of a specified nutral location and sets the total amount to a cookie which I call on an external .js page.

Below is a snippet from the .js which draws the pi chart.

```
// Pie Chart
function getCookieValue(a) {
  var b = document.cookie.match('(^|[^;]+)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
  return b ? b.pop() : '';
}
var c = getCookieValue("TS");
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["certain Area", "basaeball", "loc2"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [55, 30, 4],
```

the important part is where it defines the labels as an array. I need that to be dynamic and produce multiple variables based on the length of a php array. I haven't been able to load a distinct array to a cookie variable (possibly too large?) and then there's a matter of the data array which needs to house the `COUNT` data within the individual distinct tables.

If it's not apparent, the database is MySQL, program language is primarily PHP with HTML and javascript elements.

I'm decent with PHP but interfacing javascript and php has been a struggle for me. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! Thank you all for your time and consideration!

Comment: javascript is client baesd and php is server based, ajax can get new data from the server without loading the hole page, but even ajax starts in the client and get data from a php script. that is why you can add php data to your  javascript and html, but you need something lake ajax to send data to php

Comment: I tried looking into AJAX but I guess I was using it wrong?? for some reason AJAX wasn't storing data correctly between the two pages. This is designed to grab the data dynamically whereas with AJAX it needs to be ran based on certain params.

I could be totally wrong on that front, but that's just how I understood it

Comment: ajax call www.yourdomain.de/mypage.php?id=1&mydata=abcde ..and it can process the returned data and add/update it to your webpage via javascript

Comment: Didn't know you could do that with AjAX! I'll look more into it. I know in PHP you would use $_GET['data'] for the url data, do you have a brief explanation on grabbing datra with AJAX?

Comment: look for example at this guide http://programmerblog.net/jquery-ajax-get-example-php-mysql/ but there a lots more